# Dialog Framework References

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, dialog-framework

One of the new features in SP 2010 is the dialog framework, so that the user is presented with a uniform UI.  What are the best references or tutorials you've seen about this feature?  So far, [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/jfrost/archive/2009/11/08/how-to-display-a-sharepoint-dialog-from-ribbon-button-and-get-selected-item-context.aspx) is the best one I've seen, but it's just one simple example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the only resource you will need to learn about it:
http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2010/05/sharepoint-2010-part-2-preparing-for-70.html

Answer (score 2):

Another sample:
http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2009/12/08/sharepoint-2010-dev-tidbit-ndash-want-to-create-your-own.aspx